# How to get result of same query in same queries where condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to merge two queries into a single one.

My first query provide a result id which I check whether or not it is present in the second query.

Query #1:

```
SELECT 
    "article_messages"."id" 
FROM 
    "article_messages" 
WHERE 
    (group_id IN (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,17) 
     AND load_time <= 10 
     AND (start_time <= '2020-05-21 07:29:21.401068' AND end_time >= '2020-05-21 07:29:21.401103'))
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM "messages" 
WHERE (article_message_id = 7);
```

Is there any solution? I tried to used inner join but again get stuck as this article message id how can I get result of same query in its where condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT am.id, count(*)
FROM article_messages am
LEFT JOIN messages m ON am.id = m.article_message_id
WHERE group_id in (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,17)
  AND load_time <= 10
  AND start_time <= '2020-05-21 07:29:21.401068'
  AND end_time >= '2020-05-21 07:29:21.401103'
  AND recp_id = 1
GROUP BY am.id;
```

This lists article IDs along with their count

Comment: But it is giving only common value, I want all value from article messages table and from messages table value is 1 or anything depending on count but if not present then it should be zero  but using this query it neglect record which is not present in messages table

Comment: It sounds like you would want a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`.  This way it will show items from `article_messages` even if there is no match on `messages`.  I'll update the example in my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: please add one more thing it it  recp_id = 1 which is present in messages table I think due to this even after adding left join I don't get desire solution

Comment: I've updated the example with your additional condition.

Comment: I just checked, It is ignoring the row which is not present in message table.
i.e I have 3 records in article_message  with id 1,2,3 and only 2 record in message table  with id 2,3  then in above query I want  count is 0 for id 1

Answer (score 0):

You could just try an inner join between the two tables:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM messages m
INNER JOIN article_messages am
    ON m.article_message_id = am.id
WHERE
    am.group_id IN (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,17) AND
    am.load_time <= 10 AND
    (am.start_time <= '2020-05-21 07:29:21.401068' AND
     am.end_time >= '2020-05-21 07:29:21.401103');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "messages" 
WHERE 
  article_message_id in (
    SELECT "article_messages"."id" FROM "article_messages" 
    WHERE (
        group_id in (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 17) 
        AND load_time <= 10 
        AND (
          start_time <= '2020-05-21 07:29:21.401068' 
          AND end_time >= '2020-05-21 07:29:21.401103'
        )
      )
```

Simply filter the first table result with the second query.